# MS Access last() results are sometimes wrong

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an MS Access query that uses last() but sometimes it doesn't work as expected--which I know is what's expected lol.  But I need to find a solution, either in Access or by converting the below query to MySQL.  Any suggestions?

```
SELECT maindata.TrendShort, Last(maindata.Resistance) AS LastOfResistance, Last(maindata.Support) AS LastOfSupport, Count(maindata.ID) AS Days, Max(maindata.Datestamp) AS Datestamp, maindata.ProductID
FROM market_opinion AS maindata
WHERE (((Exists (select * from market_opinion action_count where maindata.ProductID = action_count.ProductID  and maindata.Datestamp < action_count.Datestamp and maindata.TrendShort<> action_count.TrendShort))=False))
GROUP BY maindata.TrendShort, maindata.ProductID
ORDER BY Count(maindata.ID) DESC;
```

Only the LastOfResistence and LastOfSupport are occasionally wrong, the other fields are always correct.

```
CREATE TABLE `market_opinion` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProductID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Trend` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TrendShort` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Resistance` decimal(9,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Support` decimal(9,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `Username` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Datestamp` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ProductID` (`ProductID`),
  KEY `Datestamp` (`Datestamp`),
  KEY `TrendShort` (`TrendShort`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9536 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to know quite what you're trying to get for a result. Are you looking for last record entered (e.g., date) or maximum value of resistance? Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, the last values entered (for Resistence and Support) with a count of how many times since that ProductID's Trend field changed.. I'm not sure how to give an example since the data would be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

Without some feel for the data, this becomes something of a guess, but what I'm thinking is that the Last(Resistance) and the Last(Support) aren't necessarily pulling from the same record as Max(DateStamp).  You might try breaking your query out into a 2 part query, such as:

```
Select maindata.TrendShort, Resistance, Support, COUNT(ID) as Days, ProductId
FROM market_opinion maindata
INNER JOIN (SELECT mo.TrendShort, MAX(mo.DateStamp) AS MaxDate
    FROM market_opinion mo
    WHERE (((EXISTS(SELECT ...))=FALSE))
GROUP BY mo.TrendShort) inner
WHERE maindata.TrendShort=inner.TrendSort AND maindata.DateStamp = inner.MaxDate
ORDER BY Days DESC;
```

I've left out the bulk of your query where the ellipsis (...) is, I wouldn't expect any changes there.  You might consider looking at http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=42291 for a discussion of first/last vs min/max.  Let me know if this gets you any closer.  If not, maybe some sample data where it's not working out.  It might give some insight into what's going on.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: First and Last are absolutely useless unless you know that all "aggregated" values will in fact be the same. You have no influence whatsoever on their return values since they return the "physically first" or last. Not even an ORDER BY is going to help with these.

Answer (score 0):

`First` or `Last` just returns *some* (arbitrary) record that is not the last or first respectively.

In most cases, simply use `Min` for the first and `Max` for the last.